# Scroll to 10px above an element

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using the following code to scroll to the top of an element but I'd like to scroll 10px above the top of the element, not sure how I could do this, any suggestions? Thanks!

```
  $('html, body').stop(true,true).animate({
             scrollTop: $(".career-overlay").offset().top
    }, 2000)
```

Answer (score 16):

Like this:

```
$('html, body').stop(true,true).animate({
    scrollTop: $(".career-overlay").offset().top - 10
}, 2000)
```

Comment: My mistake!  It should indeed be minus 10 rather than plus ten!  Thanks to mcpDESIGNS for fixing that one!